# select from drop down list and color picker according to div properties

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to set selected item for the drop down list based on the title attribute of a div and set the selected color of color picker (style ="background-color: ..." of div) using jQuery.

My source code (from Firebug):

```
<div class = "rsApt" title ="sql"></div>
<div style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 51);" class="rsAptOut">
  <select style="width: 100px;" 
          id="ddl_editCourse" 
          onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddl_editCourse\',\'\')', 0)" 
          name="ddl_editCourse">
    <option value="001">oop1</option>
    <option value="002">sql</option>
    <option value="003">WPF</option>
    <option value="004">c#</option>
  </select>
  <div style="width: 261px; z-index: 4000;" 
       class="RadColorPicker RadColorPicker_Default " 
       id="cp_edit">
    <label class="rcpIcon" 
           title="Pick Color (Current Color is blank)"
           id="cp_edit_label">
      <a href="#">Pick Color</a>
      <em style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" id="cp_edit_icon">(Current Color is )</em>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" 
           name="cp_edit_ClientState" 
           id="cp_edit_ClientState"
           autocomplete="off" 
           value="{&quot;selectedColor&quot;:null}">
      <div class="rcpPalette" 
           id="cp_edit_palette"
           style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; width: 259px; left: 107px; top: 75px; display: none;">
    <div class="rcpHeader">
      <a class="rcpEmptyColor" 
         href="#" title="No Color"
         id="cp_edit_emptycolor">
        <span>No Color</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rcpViews">
      <div class="rcpPageView" id="cp_edit_webPalette">
        <ul class="rcpWebPalette">
          <li>
            <a class="rcpColorBox" 
               style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"
               href="#" 
               title="#000000">
              <span style="width: 8px; height: 8px;">#000000</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="rcpColorBox" 
               style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 51);"
               href="#" 
               title="#000033">
              <span style="width: 8px; height: 8px;">#000033</span></a>
          </li>
          <!-- Additional colors ellided, the list goes on... -->
          <!-- [...] -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to do this before show dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".rsAptContent").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('rsAptDelete')) {
    }
    else {
        ShowDialog(true);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you tidy up the HTML in your example above? Just a bit of a nightmare trying to read it as it currently is.

Comment: Edited,I hope some help.

Comment: Tried to make your HTML a little more readable. (Copying code from Firebug is not the best practice IMO.)

Comment: thanks a lot , i know but trying to explain what i want to do, this problem from yesterday ,and no one answer the question:(

Answer (score 1):

maybe here you'll find a hint: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```
$("#ddl_editCourse").change(function () {
      $("#ddl_editCourse option:selected").each(function () {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', $(".rsApt").css('backgroundColor'));
          });
    })
```

this will only set the selected options ., probably you'll have to set the unselected ones too back to a default value - this you'll manage !?

(i did not test that code ....)

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work.i need when clicking on the content of my cell , setting selected value for drop down list and set the picker color in the following event:

`$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".rsAptContent").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('rsAptDelete')) {
    }
    else {
        ShowDialog(true);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
`
before show dialog() method

Comment: i dont see an element with the class **rsAptContent** in your pasted source code ..